# Contar registros en Laravel Query Builder

Tags: sql, laravel

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente

$request->mff = es un array

```
DB::table('malformacion_pacientes')
      ->whereIn('malformacion_pacientes.nombremalformacion_id', $request->mff)
      ->LEFTJOIN('mal_formaciones AS mf', 
      'malformacion_pacientes.nombremalformacion_id', '=', 'mf.id_nombremalformacion')

      ->LEFTJOIN('formaciones AS f', 
      'f.id', '=', 'mf.formacione_id')

      ->LEFTJOIN('nombremalformacions AS nm', 
      'nm.id', '=', 'mf.id_nombremalformacion')
      ->select('f.name as nombreTipoMalFormacion','nm.name as nombre')
      ->get();
```

Esa consulta me retorna lo siguiente:

[image: Resultado de consulta]

Y quiero contar cuantos registro con el campo nombreTipoMalFormacion hay en la consulta.

Como también contar cuanto registros con el valor del campo nombre se repite.

Es para hacer un reporte

De este tipo

[image: capture del reporte que busco hacer]

Eh intentando contar con cláusulas

```
 COUNT(CASE WHEN f.name as nombreTipoMalFormacion = 'MFC' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS MFC,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN f.name as nombreTipoMalFormacion = 'MSNC' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS MSNC,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN f.name as nombreTipoMalFormacion = 'MFR' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS MFR,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN f.name as nombreTipoMalFormacion = 'MFG' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS MFG
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN f.name as nombreTipoMalFormacion = 'MFME' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS MFME
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN f.name as nombreTipoMalFormacion = 'MFSR' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS MFSR
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN f.name as nombreTipoMalFormacion = 'MFSRP' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS MFSRP
```

Sin obtener resultados positivos.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer, es utilizar el método `countBy()` ([Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-countBy))

La consulta que muestras la guardo en una variable `$query` para poder mostrar como funciona `countBy()`

```
$query = DB::table('malformacion_pacientes')
      ->whereIn('malformacion_pacientes.nombremalformacion_id', $request->mff)
      ->LEFTJOIN('mal_formaciones AS mf', 
      'malformacion_pacientes.nombremalformacion_id', '=', 'mf.id_nombremalformacion')

      ->LEFTJOIN('formaciones AS f', 
      'f.id', '=', 'mf.formacione_id')

      ->LEFTJOIN('nombremalformacions AS nm', 
      'nm.id', '=', 'mf.id_nombremalformacion')
      ->select('f.name as nombreTipoMalFormacion','nm.name as nombre')
      ->get();
```

A la colección que devuelve la consulta le aplicamos el método `countBy()` de la siguiente forma (No estoy seguro de la composición completa de tu tabla así que podría necesitar adaptaciones

```
$malformaciones = $query->countBy(function ($item) {
                      return $item['nombreTipoMalFormacion'];
                  });
$enfermedades = $query->countBy(function ($item) {
                    return $item['nombreEnfermedad'];
                });
```

Te dejo un ejemplo genérico por si tienes que hacer algún cambio puedas ver como funciona de forma general. En este caso  `$collection` está simulando una colección, pero en tu caso la colección se forma de la respuesta de tu consulta a la base de datos

```
public function index()
{
    $collection = collect([
            ["id"=>1, "name"=>"Hardik", "role"=>"Admin"],
            ["id"=>2, "name"=>"Paresh", "role"=>"Admin"],
            ["id"=>3, "name"=>"Rakesh", "role"=>"User"],
        ]);
  
    $count = $collection->countBy(function ($item) {
                    return $item['role'];
                });
        
    dd($count);
}
```

Esto produce:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object

(

    [items:protected] => Array

        (

            [Admin] => 2

            [User] => 1

        )

)
```

Como puedes ver, el ejemplo cuenta cada valor diferente de `role`

Comment: Esta es la solucion acertada. Gracias de verdad

Comment: Ahora tengo otra duda, lo que retorna como lo manipulo?, es un array?, json?.